# Common Eigenvalues of a Commuted Matrix Product

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Can we prove that $AB$ and $BA$ share all nonzero eigenvalues?

Based on comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435831/if-a-and-b-are-positive-definite-then-is-b-1-a-1-positive-semidef), this appears to be possible.

Comment: See, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821934/eigenvalues-of-ab-and-ba-matrices). The question considers square $A$ and $B$ but some proofs work also for rectangular matrices.

Comment: Great. Clears it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $AB u = \lambda u$, what can you say about $BA (Bu)$?