# Eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the MIT linear algebra online lecture, when doing SVD, Gilbert Strang said that the eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ are the same. I was trying to prove this as follows:

Let $A$ be $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ be $n \times m$ matrix. Then $AB$ is $m \times m$ and $BA$ is $n \times n$.

Let
$$ABx=\lambda x$$
Then
$$BA(Bx)=\lambda(Bx)$$
and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ as well, and vice versa. Q.E.D.

However, after a second thought I think the above proof has a pitfall. Namely, if $x$ is in the null-space of $B$ then $BA$ needs not have eigenvalue $\lambda$.

So my questions is:

Is the statement that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues true for general $m \times n$ matrix $A$ and $n \times m$ matrix $B$? If yes, how to prove it?

If no, is it true for the special case when $B=A^\dagger$? And how to prove it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your proof is correct for $\lambda\neq 0$, because then it isn't possible that you get $Bx=0$ for an eigenvector $x$ of $AB$ to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

And this is also the general statement: All non zero eigenvalues are the same. That it doesn't works  with $\lambda=0$ you see for $A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

For another proof look at the characteristic polynomial. See [en.wikipedia.org/Characteristic polynomial of a product of two matrices.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_a_product_of_two_matrices)

Answer (score 0):

$BA=BABB^-1$ 
$BA=B\cdot AB\cdot B^-1$ 
Let $M=B^-1$ 
$BA=M^-1\cdot AB\cdot M$ 
So, $AB$ and $BA$ are similar matrices. Hence they have same eigenvalues.

**Edit 1:**
As rightly pointed by [Hanul Jeon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53976/hanul-jeon), this holds only if $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices

Comment: Does $B$ have an inverse matrix? I think you cannot define its inverse matrix in general.

Comment: @HanulJeon, you're right. This hold only if $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices. I've updated the answer