# Characteristic polynomials of $AB$ and $BA$

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation

For simplicity, consider $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, the set of $2\times 2$ real matrices.

> **Fact:** For any $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, $AB$ and $BA$ have same characteristic polynomials.

The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_a_product_of_two_matrices) proof is as follows:

(1) $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ can be identified topologically with Euclidean topological space $\mathbb{R}^4$

(2) $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

(3) The **fact** is true for $A,B$ in this open subset; hence true for $M_2(\mathbb{R}).$

**Question 1:** Can one clarify a little the argument (3)?

**Question 2.** How should the proof be modified for arbitrary field $K$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your questions, but [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061035/eigenvalues-of-ab-and-ba-the-same) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just that it's an open subset. The important thing is that it's a *dense* open subset. In the Zariski topology this should work over arbitrary fields, as the general linear group is a dense open subset in the Zariski topology. (I haven't really checked the details of this; there may be some caveat that I missed).